# Laravel 4 filter relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the "examples" table, the "tags" table and intermediate "examples_has_tags" table. So one example can have some tags and one tag can belong to some examples.

In index.php I show all examples and tag list.

```
$examples = Example::with('tags')->where('public', true)->get();

$tags = Tag::all();

return View::make('index')->with('examples', $examples)
                          ->with('tags',     $tags);
```

Works perfectly.
But how can I filter examples by tag name?  I found something on stackoverflow: you should create a static method in Example class which returns what I need. But I got messy with displaying data. In the code above I display it like:

```
@foreach ($examples as $example)
        <div class="widgetbox">
            <h4 class="widgettitle">{{ $example->name }}</h4>
            <div class="widgetcontent">
                {{ $example->body }}
                <div class="tags-list">
                    @foreach ($example->tags as $tag)
                        <span class="label label-info tag">{{ $tag->name }}</span>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I found something about filtering collections but there is  no examples

**update**

I found the next solution:

```
    $examples = $examples->filter(function($example) {
        $tags = $example->tags->toArray();
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if ($tag["name"] == Input::get('tag')) return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

**update2**

Tried to do this without PHP filtering, but I can't get tags which belongs to an example:

```
$tagId = Tag::where('name', '=', Input::get('tag'))->first()->id;

        $examples = Example::with('tags')
                           ->join('examples_has_tags', 'examples_has_tags.example_id', '=', 'examples.id')
                           ->where('examples_has_tags.tag_id', '=', $tagId)->get();
```

$examples doesn't contain tags list (it's empty actually)

Comment: What about my alternative (in_array) approach, can you please check it ?

Comment: Didn't work, $example->tags->toArray() returns not just array("tagName1", "tagName2"...) so... I tried array_pluck but without success (don't know why id didn't work for me).

Comment: Is your solution working ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows ([Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading))

**Model :** (Example)

```
class Example extends Eloquent {
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Tag');
    }
}
```

Now query :

```
$examples = Example::with(array('tags' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('name', '=', 'someName');
}))->get();
```

**Update :**

```
$examples = $examples->filter(function($example) {
    $tags = $example->tags->toArray();
    return in_array(Input::get('tag'), $tags ) ?: FALSE;
});
```

Comment: As I understand I will get all examples and in each example I will have filtered tags. But this is not what I am trying to get - I want to filter examples list itself. I think I've already tried your solution but I'll check in a couple of hours, thanks

Comment: Look at my solution in my post (I updated it). Seems like it works

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a join, and then create a where clause on the stuff you want. Depending on how you want to filter by tag, you might do something like this:

First fetch the valid tag ids:

```
$tagIDs = array_pluck(Tag::whereIn('name', array(
    'tag1',
    'tag2',
    'tag3',
))->toArray(), 'id');
```

Then filter the examples by tag_id:

```
return Example::select('examples.*')
    ->join('examples_has_tags', 'examples.id', '=', DB::raw('examples_has_tags.example_id'))
    ->whereIn(DB::raw('examples_has_tags.tag_id'), $tagIDs)
    ->get();
```

There may be (and probably are) more efficient ways of doing this, but this is how I would approach it.

Comment: What about my solution (I updated my post) ? Seems like it works

Comment: Yes, this your solution should work. However, there is a difference. You are doing the filtering using PHP. This is slower than a DB engine, because it isn't optimised to do this.

Also, you're fetching ALL Examples into your script, and then later start the filtering. Imagine having a database with 1.000.000 records... it would become extremely slow. If you let the DB engine do the filtering, you wouldn't (really) have this problem.

Comment: I guess you're right, but how can I get tags list for each example? Look at update2 in my post. Since I filter only by one tag, I slightly changed the query, and I don't use DB::raw as it works without that. I  get right examples but I when I loop through them I and try to display tags list for each example (like @foreach($example->tags as $tag) the tags array is empty...